# My isLoading flag never set true in the constructor()

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I'm working whith one representational component (ProjectFormUpdate) and his container (ProjectFormUpdateContainer).  From the container, i send an document object Project and a flag isLoading. But in a Constructor() of ProjectFormUpdate, the flag is false... the state is never seted.

The representational componente

```
    import React, { Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Projects } from '/imports/api/projects.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';


export default class ProjectFormUpdate extends Component {
  handleUpdate(event) {
     event.preventDefault();  
     console.log("se modificó el estadoooo") 
     this.setState({
      codigo: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.codigoInput).value.trim(),
      nombre: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nombreInput).value.trim()
    });

   }

  handleSubmit(event){

     this.setState({
      codigo: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.codigoInput).value.trim(),
      nombre: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nombreInput).value.trim()
    });

  }


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
        if (!props.isLoading){

        this.state = {      
          codigo: props.oneProject.codigo,
          nombre: props.oneProject.nombre}       
        }
        else{

          this.state = {      
          codigo: 'dd',
          nombre: 'ff'}    
        }  
      }

  render() {

    const { oneProject, isLoading } = this.props;

    if (!isLoading){
      this.setState = {      
          codigo: this.props.oneProject.codigo,
          nombre: this.props.oneProject.nombre}       




    return (
      <div className="col-xs-11">
       <div className="box box-solid">
         <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
         <div className="box-body">
                  <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-xs-2">
                              <input
                                className = "form-control input-sm"
                                type="text"
                                ref="codigoInput"
                                placeholder="Código del Proyecto"
                                value = {this.state.codigo}//this.state.codigo}
                                onChange = {this.handleUpdate.bind(this)}
                              />
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-xs-6">
                              <input
                                className = "form-control input-sm"
                                type="text"
                                ref="nombreInput"
                                placeholder="Título"
                                value = {this.state.nombre }
                                onChange = {this.handleUpdate.bind(this)}
                              />
                           </div>
                </div>


        </div>
        <div className="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-flat">Guardar</button>
        </div>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>

    );
  }
  else {return (<div></div>);}
}}

ProjectFormUpdate.propTypes = {
  // This component gets the task to display through a React prop.
  // We can use propTypes to indicate it is required
  oneProject: React.PropTypes.object,   
  isLoading: React.PropTypes.bool, 
};
```

The Container

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Projects } from '/imports/api/projects.js';
import ProjectFormUpdate from './ProjectFormUpdate.jsx';

export default ProjectFormUpdateContainer = withTracker(({ key1 }) => {      
    const sub = Meteor.subscribe('projects');        
    var oneProject = Projects.findOne(key1);
    var isLoading = !sub.ready();    
    return {
        oneProject,
        isLoading,
    };      
})(ProjectFormUpdate);
```

So... if i can't set the state, i can't set the form's values in a controled way. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set your components state outside of the `constructor()` function: you must call [`this.setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). `this.setState()` will set it's first argument as the new state and subsequently call your component's render function.

Your `if (!isLoading)` statement is very dangerous. Assuming `!isLoading == true`: your render function will infinitely fire `this.setState()`, thereby locking your browser.

Your constructor function appears correct, as is. I would allow it to set the initial application state and handle the rest from within the `render()` function. Alternatively, you could set your initial state within the `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()` functions [found here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount).

Within your `render()` function, I would omit the `if (!isLoading)` part and instead try returning a loading component `if (isLoading == true)`.

You can also apply the following logic directly to your `<input/>` elements to set your component's state with finesse:

```
<input value={this.state.key} onChange={(event) => this.setState({key: event.target.value})}/>
```

I've revised your `ProjectFormUpdate` component as follows:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Projects } from '/imports/api/projects.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export default class ProjectFormUpdate extends Component {

handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log()
}


constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  if (!props.isLoading) {
    this.state = {
      codigo: props.oneProject.codigo,
      nombre: props.oneProject.nombre
    }
  }
  else {
    this.state = {
      codigo: '',
      nombre: ''
    }
  }
}

render() {

  const { oneProject, isLoading } = this.props;

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>isLoading == true</div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-xs-11">
      <div className="box box-solid">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
          <div className="box-body">
          <div className="row">
            {/* Codigo. */}
            <div className="col-xs-2">
              <input className = "form-control input-sm" type="text" ref="codigoInput" placeholder="Código del Proyecto" value={this.state.codigo} onChange={(event) => this.setState({codigo: event.target.value})} />
            </div>

            {/* Nombre. */}
            <div className="col-xs-6">
              <input className = "form-control input-sm" type="text" ref="nombreInput" placeholder="Título" value={this.state.nombre} onChange={(event) => this.setState({nombre: event.target.value}))} />
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-flat">Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ProjectFormUpdate.propTypes = {
  oneProject: React.PropTypes.object,
  isLoading: React.PropTypes.bool,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arman. Your code helped me so much. But, unfortunelly I've not find a solution seting the state. If i do it in constructor, or in componentWillMount() or in componentDidMount()... the state it's never set becouse isLoading is always true.

Comment: Hi mate. Very glad I could help. That would suggest that your `const sub = Meteor.subscribe('projects')` method is not returning `true` for `.ready()`. I would check that you've implemented the argument correctly using the following docs: [React Meteor Data](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/tree/devel/packages/react-meteor-data) and [Meteor.subscribe()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe). Setting console logs for the outputs of the `.onReady()` and `.onStop()` callback functions might help. All the best!